# How to append a list to a file on Python using JSON

Tags: python, json, file, list, append

I'm getting a bit of a trouble here. I have a text file with `["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"]`, and I want to make that *if* `data1` is not in the file, then append a new list with all three strings, and if data is already there, then just print it. What is broken in this code and why?

```
filename = "datosdeusuario.txt"
leyendo = open(filename, 'r')
if user.name in leyendo:
  Print("Your user name is already there")
else:
  file = open(filename, 'a')
  file.write(json.dumps([user.name, "data2", "data3"])+"\n")
  file.close()
  Print("Since I couldn't find it, I did append your name and data.")
```

P.S.: I am a rookie in Python, and I'm getting confused often. That's why I am not using any dicts (no idea what they are anyway), so I'd like to make that code work in the most simple way.

P.S.2: Also, if that works, my next step would be to make a search engine to return one specific of the three data items in the list. For example, if I want to get the data2 in a list with username "sael", what would I need to do?

Comment: Where is `user.name` defined? What does the function `Print` do? (did you mean the built-in function `print`? Capitalization matters.) Are you getting an error message, or is the program running but not behaving the way you expect?

Comment: lazyy001 gave a good answer, and now i'm in the 2nd part of the problem. How do i get an specific data from the file?

The user.name information is not really neccesary to understand this code and is built into the library that i'm using. Also by print i meant the built-in function. Sorry about the capitalizing issue :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're reading from the file pointer, NOT from the data in the file as you expected.

So, you first need to read the data in the file:

```
buffer = leyendo.read()
```

Then do your check based on `buffer`, not `leyendo`:

```
if user.name in buffer:
```

Also, you're opening the file two times, that may be kind of expensive. I am not sure if Python got a feature to open the file in both read and write modes.

Comment: Indeed, that was the fail, thanks for the answer. Also python got a mode r+ to Read and Write at same time, seems a good option but i wasn't sure if would work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your user.name and your `Print` functions are working, you need to read the file and close the file.

Try this:

```
filename = "datosdeusuario.txt"
f = open(filename, 'r')
leyendo = f.read()
f.close()
if user.name in leyendo:
  Print("Your user name is already there")
else:
  file = open(filename, 'a')
  file.write(json.dumps([user.name, "data2", "data3"])+"\n")
  file.close()
  Print("Since I couldn't find it, I did append your name and data.")
```

Comment: Working so far. Well... working sometimes lol. It's suppose to get the information from each message in a chat and so far it's only getting the 90% of them. Some of the messages gets ignored and it saves nothing. Might be because it takes some time to close and open the file or could be something else? I only got troubles with this piece of code. without using the module json it gets the 100% messages.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391165/how-to-retrieve-specific-string-from-specific-list-from-a-file-with-json-in-pyth

Answer (score 1):

First, you should close the file in both cases, and I think you should close the file before re-opening it for appending.

I think the problem is with the line:

```
if user.name in leyendo:
```

which will always return false.

You should read the file and then question it like so:

```
if user.name in leyendo.read():
```